# Symfony: question about jq_link_to_remote()

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony1

i have a template with this below to show a dialog when the link is clicked:

```
<div id="myDialog">

</div>

echo jq_link_to_remote('Enviar mensaje 2', array(
                                        'url' => 'mensaje/new?receptor='.$miembro->getId().'&tipo=0&estado=0',

                                       'update' => "$('#myDialog')",

                                        'complete' => '$("#myDialog").dialog({ height:530 });
                                    ));
```

When i click the link, i get in Firebug the message:

> $("#myDialog") is null

and no dialog appears.

Any idea?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 1):

This below now is working. I'm loading another javascript framework, so i have to replace "$" by "jQuery".

```
echo jq_link_to_remote('Enviar mensaje', array(

              'url' => 'mensaje/new?receptor='.$miembro->getId().'&tipo=0&estado=0',

              'update' => 'myDialog',

              'complete' => "jQuery('#myDialog').dialog()"
            ));
```